# How to cut the files from one folder and paste to another folder in mac OS?

Tags: macos

I have tried to find the shortcut to cut the files from one folder and paste to another folder but couldn't find any shortcut. Please me if someone know the shortcut.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You still copy the files with the same shortcut, but when pasting the following command will actually move rather than copy: `Command-Opt-V`.

See http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/29/cut-and-paste-mac-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 3):

Drag and drop.

**Or** select your files. `Command + c` to copy. `Command + Alt/Option + v` to move. Thanks @DanielFlint

**Or** select your files. `Command + c` to copy. `Command + v` to paste.

**Or** just `mv /path/to/targetFile /path/to/destinationFolder` in terminal.

Comment: I know how to copy files but I asked how to cut the files.

Comment: Means, there is no shortcut to cut the files like other OS does. Right?

Comment: @sushilprj well really it would take you two operations to copy then move (it will select the file, and when you move it, it deletes the original file) so it's equivalent in every way to cut and paste other than deletion upon selection. I would assume it's just another philosophy of file management.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to cut and paste is `command-opt-V`, this way the copies files will be removed from the initial/source folder thus works as cut&paste. Otherwise it is not directly supported.